# SQL Declare Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables

Can anyone check on my statement...

```
DECLARE @tblName varchar(MAX), 
        @strSQL varchar(MAX)

SET @tblName ='SELECT DISTINCT o.name as TableName 
                 FROM sysobjects o 
                 JOIN sysindexes x on o.id = x.id  
                WHERE o.name LIKE ''%empty%'''  

SET @strSQL = 'INSERT INTO @tblName VALUES(''trylng'', ''1'')'
EXEC (@strSQL)
```

my error is...

> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the table variable "@tblName".

Comment: I hope there're only two columns in whatever table gets returned, and the data type match...

Comment: @OMGPonies: You mean insertable columns, of course.

Answer (score 12):

Your `@tblName` property exists at the outer scope - the scope of your "normal" code lines - but not at the inner scope of the SQL you're constructing in the string there....

You need to change your lines to read:

```
SET @strSQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tblName + ' VALUES(''trylng'', ''1'')'
```

and then it should work just fine.

Also, you're not mentioning your SQL Server version - but as of SQL Server 2005 or newer, you should stop using `sysobjects` and `sysindexes` - instead, use the new `sys` schema that contains more or less the same information - but more easily available. Change your query to:

```
SET @tblName ='SELECT DISTINCT t.name as TableName 
               FROM sys.tables t
               INNER JOIN sys.indexes i on i.object_id = t.object_id  
               WHERE t.name LIKE ''%empty%'''
```

See [MSDN: Querying the SQL Server System Catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189082.aspx) for a lot more information on what's available in the new `sys` schema and how to make the most of it!

As "rsbarro" pointed out : putting this SQL statement here into quotes is odd - are you executing this statement using `EXEC(...)`, too?? But then how do you assign the value back to the `@tblName` property? Doesn't really make sense.....

If you want to actually run this query to get a value, you should have something like this:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 @tblName = t.name
 FROM sys.tables t
 INNER JOIN sys.indexes i on i.object_id = t.object_id  
 WHERE t.name LIKE '%empty%'
```

You need to have a `TOP 1` in there to be **sure** to get just a single value - otherwise this statement could fail (if multiple rows are selected).

Comment: Am I missing something? Why is @tblName wrapped in single quotes? Won't that just set it equal to the string, and not the table name?

Comment: No, I mean the second statement. Shouldn't it read `SET @tblName = SELECT DISTINCT t.name...` without quotes? The way it is written @strSQL will have a value of `INSERT INTO SELECT DISTINCT t.Name as TableName...`. Seems to me that will be invalid, no?

Comment: @rsbarro: ah ok - well, not sure - I was assuming the OP would be executing that SQL statement using `EXEC(....)` as well. If not - then you're absolutely right, it won't work!

Comment: Cool. It's late where I'm at, and I thought I was either seeing some new syntax or losing my mind... =]

Comment: Another question...why do we need to use join to SYS.INDEXES since on the list of tables that match to our "WHERE" are in the SYS.TABLES..??

Comment: @ArgelJoseph: I don't know why you're using `sys.indexes` - that was your statement, I just tried to make it work. But you're right - the `sys.indexes` seems unneeded here in that statement....

Answer (score 6):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I think you want something like this:

```
DECLARE @tblName varchar(MAX), @strSQL varchar(MAX)
SET @tblName = 
    (select distinct o.name as TableName 
     from sysobjects o 
     join sysindexes x on o.id = x.id  
     where o.name LIKE '%empty%')
SET @strSQL = 'INSERT INTO [' + @tblName + '] VALUES(''trylng'', ''1'')'
exec (@strSQL)
```

That being said, there are still a couple things to watch out for here. You need to handle the condition where the `SELECT DISTINCT` returns anything other than a single record. Also, I don't really understand the need to build dynamic SQL (in `@strSQL`) when `@tblName` will always have the same value (since there are no variables used in the `WHERE` clause).

Comment: +1, only one note: generally it is safer to incorporate names into dynamic scripts like this: `'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@tblName) + '…'`, rather than simply to put square brackets around them.