# Declaring SQL variables - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, variables, declare

Can anyone check on my statement...

```
DECLARE @tblName varchar(MAX), 
        @strSQL varchar(MAX)

SET @tblName ='SELECT DISTINCT o.name as TableName 
                 FROM sysobjects o 
                 JOIN sysindexes x on o.id = x.id  
                WHERE o.name LIKE ''%empty%'''  

SET @strSQL = 'INSERT INTO @tblName VALUES(''trylng'', ''1'')'
EXEC (@strSQL)
```

my error is...

> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the table variable "@tblName".

What I want to do is get the table name on the variable `@tblName` and insert some data in `@strSQL` variable

For example... the result in `@tblName` is `CustomerInfo`

then in `@strSQL` I will going to use the result in `@tblName` as my table name in my Insert Command.

So the `@strSQL` variable will be;

```
INSERT INTO CustomerInfo VALUES(......)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Declare Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407703/sql-declare-variables)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Declare Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407703/sql-declare-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this from my answer to your other question:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 @tblName = t.name
 FROM sys.tables t
 INNER JOIN sys.indexes i on i.object_id = t.object_id  
 WHERE t.name LIKE '%empty%'

 SET @strSQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tblName  + ' VALUES(''trylng'', ''1'')'
 EXEC (@strSQL)
```

You're **still** not mentioning the SQL Server version you're using. But as of SQL Server 2005 or newer, you should stop using `sysobjects` and `sysindexes` - instead, use the new `sys` schema that contains more or less the same information - but more easily available.

See [MSDN: Querying the SQL Server System Catalog][1] for a lot more information on what's available in the new `sys` schema and how to make the most of it!

Comment: oops, my bad,, I'm using SQL Server 2008, nway..thanks 4 d help

Comment: another thing...what if i am going to use an IF Statement in @strSQL before the insert Command because i want to verify first if the values that i'm going to insert in not existing in the table. 

sorry for many questions...coz i'm only starting to study the sql.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare more than one variable with a single DECLARE statement, [you only put the type once](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html) (at the end):

```
DECLARE @tblName, @strSQL varchar(MAX)
```

Comment: I could have sworn the original question was about MySql (which is what I answered).  It appears Sql Server allows duplicate type definitions in DECLARE statements

Comment: This answer is incorrect. SQL Server does NOT allow `DECLARE @tblName, @strSQL varchar(MAX)`. One *must* specify the type of each variable like: `declare @i int, @t varchar(max);`

Answer (score 1):

This should be something can really run:

```
DECLARE @tblName varchar(MAX), 
        @strSQL varchar(MAX)

SET @tblName =  (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1  o.name as TableName 
                 FROM sysobjects o 
                 JOIN sysindexes x on o.id = x.id  
                WHERE o.name LIKE '%empty%')

SET @strSQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tblName + ' VALUES(''trylng'', ''1'')'
EXEC (@strSQL)
```

Anything in quote means that's a string and don't expect sql server run it as statement, same thing to the variable in a string, you can't quote it

Comment: `DSINTINCT` **and** `TOP 1` is a bit too much..... if you only have 1 result, it cannot possible have duplicates anyway.....

Comment: Just want to make sure it won't crash as there might be some different table have similar name